# How to hide the scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the overflow-y of an element to auto while having height at 100%, which from what I've gathered from other posts has the solution of setting the overflow-y to hidden. This however creates a scroll bar where it is not necessary.

Essentially, what I'm trying to achieve is to have an element be:

```
overflow-y: auto;
height: 100%;
```

As the auto attribute allows the scrollbar to be hidden until it is actually needed.

Thanks in advance,
PS: I did look around stackoverflow before this and couldn't find a post this specific.

Comment: link or a fiddle?..`height:100%` !what is the height of parent div?

Comment: essentially its the same as this: http://jsfiddle.net/5tfak93a/ except that this produces what I need. But it might have something to do with it being inside of a partial using angular.js

Answer (score 0):

Its a very simple solution:

you just need 2 containers: an outer container and an inner container.

the outer container has a set width and height with an overflow of hidden. the inner container has a height set (doesn't have to be a fixed value so long as it inherits a height from somewhere) with

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
```

then all you need to do to hide the scroll bar is set the inner container to have a width greater then the outer container.

## fiddle for reference ---> http://jsfiddle.net/Lj110hb4/